# BigQuery how to join 2 tables based on overlapping intervals?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert this join from Postgres to BigQuery:

```
-- postgres
SELECT *
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
ON tstzrange(table_a.start, table_a.end) && tstzrange(table_b.start, table_b.end)
```

I've tried the 4 overlapping cases but in BigQuery it doesn't work like that. My result always ends up missing some windows.

```
INNER JOIN table_b
ON 
-- case 1
a.start <= b.start AND b.end <= a.end
OR
-- case 2
a.start <= b.start AND b.start <= a.end
OR 
-- case 3
b.start <= a.start AND a.end <= b.end
OR
-- case 4
b.start <= a.start AND a.start <= b.end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the NULL value is automatically handled as lower and upper bound in Postgres `tstzrange`. It's not handled in basic queries or in BQ. Using `COALESCE()` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below condition to check if there is an overlapped period.

- `a.start <= b.end AND b.start <= a.end`

sample query is

```sql
WITH table_a AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 09:00:00' start, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 09:00:00' `end` UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-05 09:00:00' start, '2023-01-15 09:00:00' `end` 
),
table_b AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-12-15 09:00:00' start, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-04 09:00:00' `end` UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2023-01-12 09:00:00' start, '2023-01-20 09:00:00' `end`
)
SELECT * FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON a.start <= b.end AND b.start <= a.end;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your answer isn't correct.

Comment: `ON a.start <= b.end AND b.start <= a.end;` only handles 1 condition of the 2 possible overlapping intervals:
```
as  bs  ae be
```
You'll need to handle `bs as be ae` also

Comment: above sample query is `bs as be ae` case and i think it will work for `as bs ae be` as well.  kindly check the updated sample.

Comment: Just for someone who is interested in `interval overlap range join`,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/optimizations/range-join#interval-overlap-range-join